# Enable IPv6 subnet on existing GCP VCP that is not dual stack

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, ipv6

Is there any way to enable IPv6 on an existing IPv4 only subnet on a GCP VPC without rewiring everything? Currently facing an issue in production where I'm unable to reach external IPv6 resources (Firebase) because we are not on a dual-stack subnet.

Any advice or tips would be great. Looking to minimize changes to infrastructure and avoid any service disruption.

Answer (score 0):

As you said To enable IPv6 on an existing IPv4 only subnet on a GCP and you are not using dual-stack subnet

Install [NAT64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64) for your Problem

NAT64 is an [IPv6 transition mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism) that facilitates communication between [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) and [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) hosts by using a form of [network address translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (NAT). The NAT64 gateway is a translator between IPv4 and IPv6 protocols,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64) for which function it needs at least one IPv4 address and an IPv6 network segment comprising a 32-bit address space.

Refer to a [global IPv6 address be NAT'd to an internal IPv4 address at a firewall-level](https://serverfault.com/questions/465502/can-a-global-ipv6-address-be-natd-to-an-internal-ipv4-address-at-a-firewall-lev) for more information.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.